# Rich Snippet for thirdparty Logos

Tags: seo, markup, microdata

i want to add a section to my homepage with third party logos of companies i've worked for. To tell google what this section is about I want to wrap my content in a richsnippet code. 
My own logo is wrapped like this:

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<a itemprop="url" href="http://www.google.de"><!--Link to frontpage -->
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.google.de/image.jpg"/><!--Link to logo img -->
</a>
</span>
```

So if I would do it like this, google might think those are MY logos. How can i make clear these are thirdparty / reference logos? Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!
All the best

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: If I'm wrong here, I'm sorry. 
FYI Guys: I guess it should be http://schema.org/Brand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution should be: http://schema.org/Brand

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
<span itemprop="name">Brand name</span>
<a itemprop="url" href="http://www.google.de"><!--Link to frontpage -->
<img itemprop="logo" src="http://www.google.de/image.jpg"/><!--Link to logo img -->
</a>
</span>
```

Difference: Organization for the own logo, brand for the references - sidewide.